# jQuery settimeout not working with anonymous function

Tags: jquery, scope, settimeout, anonymous-function

I have this setup to add a *mouseenter* event to each of my DIVs:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('div[id^=domainEnter]').mouseenter(function () {


                toggleSearchDisplay($(this).attr('domaincount'), 'show');

            });
 });
```

Then I have this function defined:

```
  function toggleSearchDisplay(num, showhide) {

            if ($('div[id=domainDiv' + num + ']').css('display') == "block" || showhide == "hide") {
                $('div[id=domainDiv' + num + ']').hide('fast');
                $('a[id = domainLink' + num + ']').text('+');
                $('input[id ^= SearchControls_' + num + '__SearchControlVisible]').val('false');
            } else {

                $('div[id=domainDiv' + num + ']').show('fast');
                $('a[id = domainLink' + num + ']').text('-');
                $('input[id ^= SearchControls_' + num + '__SearchControlVisible]').val('true');


            }
        }
```

this all works well and does what I need it to, but now
I'm trying to get a timeout/delay setup on the MouseEnter bit in the first block... 
I tried this, and it never executes:

```
$('div[id^=domainEnter]').mouseenter(setTimeout(function () {

                toggleSearchDisplay($(this).attr('domaincount'), 'show');

            },1000));
```

I then tried this, which executes, but there's no delay... it runs normally:

```
 $('div[id^=domainEnter]').mouseenter(function () {

            setTimeout(toggleSearchDisplay($(this).attr('domaincount'), 'show'),1000);

        });
```

I don't know what to do... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first try, you're not giving  a function as argument to `mouseenter` but the result of `setTimeout`, that is a timer.

In the second one, when the callback provided to `setTimeout` is executed, `this` is the window.

Here's a way to fix it :

```
$('div[id^=domainEnter]').mouseenter(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     setTimeout(function () {
        toggleSearchDisplay($this.attr('domaincount'), 'show');
     },1000)
});
```

Comment: Also to the fact that it was not a closure, it was a direct call to the function.

Comment: I've discovered that in vanilla JS, setTimeout() and setInterval() do not work (at least on my browser) with anonymous functions. You have to provide a named function to these calls. Whether JQuery has a built in workaround for this I don't know, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @DavidEdwards I can assure you that setTimeout and setInterval do work with anonymous functions. They always did.

Comment: Can you provide an example for me to try? Only if you do, and your example works, I may have discovered something interesting about Chrome's handling of setTimeout() etc ...